# Mathematical research outside academia

Tags: soft-question, advice, career-development

My goal up through grad school had been to spend my life doing academic, research mathematics. I got screwed by my advisor and department, though, so that hasn't worked out. I would nevertheless still like to do math and somehow contribute. Is there any place outside academia that does serious, professional pure math? Ideally, I'd like to at least publish a few research papers on vaguely-mathematical topics, but it's hard to find jobs that even afford that; in fact, it's hard to find jobs that use math beyond the undergrad level. it seems like my best bet is finding something in security related to theoretical computer science, but that's not a field I have any interest in; besides, I'm not sure how interested the industry would be in someone coming in from a pure math background. So, is there any reasonable equivalent or approximation to research mathematics in industry; and, if not, what's the closest I can actually get to it?

Comment: I don't have any good advise but I just want to express my deepest condolence. I hope that you'll eventually figure out some way and be able keep on doing mathematics. Best luck to you.

Comment: @BigbearZzz: Thank you, that's very kind of you.

Comment: Post this on the academia thread

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: But it's the opposite of academia.

Comment: Trust me. There will be a lot of people who can address this on there. The name of the thread is misleading.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: The academia stackexchange is quite different from this one. I have posted there in the past, but its primary focus is on people who are farther up the academic ladder (or quickly-closed questions from people asking about their chances for undergrad/grad school/postdoc/professorship).

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: (Continued from above) More to the point, math is very different from other fields in that it's really not done in industry. It's trivial to find this sort of position in engineering and other applied fields, and there's a revolving door between academia and industry in computer science. There's really no math beyond the undergrad level involved outside academia. No one in industry cares, for example, about representation theory beyond what would be covered in the standard introductory group theory class, if even that.

Comment: Those questions get closed because there are too many variables and honestly, it's usually the case that people are looking for a pat on the back or just for someone to tell them what to do.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: Maybe. In any case, what I'm looking for is the closest approximation available to academic math research outside academia (to the extent that there is one). Given the number of PhDs in math (and, for the reasons above, it's safe to assume that the vast majority of PhDs in math want to continue in academic research) and the number of academic positions available, I can't be the only person who wants an answer to the question.

Comment: AMS has a ton of information on this type of stuff already. Have you looked there?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood: I have, yes. Ditto for mathjobs.org .

Comment: It seems you've [already asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395307/jobs-in-industry-for-pure-mathematicians?rq=1) this question.

Comment: What about places like Microsoft Research, Facebook AI Labs, etc?

Comment: @AlexR.: Do you really think that Microsoft or Facebook deal with pure math research? They may do some nontrivial research on computer-science-flavored applied math, machine learning, etc., but not much of it, and those kinds of positions are quite rare in industry. (Now, I do know a former math professor who ran a quantum computing group at Microsoft Research. That would be great, but that sort of thing is incredibly rare in industry, and it might as well be a postdoc; and if I could get a postdoc, I'd just stay in academia.)

Comment: There is duplicate on Academia.SE already: [Are there any research careers except professorship for a person holding PhD in pure mathematics?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/are-there-any-research-careers-except-professorship-for-a-person-holding-phd-in)

Comment: I know this is old but if you're a US citizen I recommend looking at NSA jobs.  I imagine getting a research-oriented position without a PhD is next to impossible.  Is there really *no* way for you to finish your PhD, even at a different school?

Comment: @tilper: I have a PhD; I just had a terrible advisor who hamstrung me in grad school and in finding later careers. I've looked into the NSA and probably will again, but it's ultimately not what I want.

Answer (score 7):

This has been here for a while, so I'm not sure it is still a current issue for you. I'm sorry an academic career hasn't worked out to be as you hoped.

If you are serious about commercial sector employment, you need to look at it
from a commercial point of view. Some large commercial companies are getting
interested in basic research, but it seems to me there is still a clear
commercial aspect to their hiring--at least from a long-term point of view.
If they are going to pay you \$100K a year, it will cost them at least \$200K
a year to have you around (social security tax, health insurance, admin and
facilities costs, and so on). So they are asking themselves what you can
do for them that makes it worth $200K a year over the long run to have you around.

Many government agencies are similarly task-oriented but in terms that are
not always expressed conveniently in dollars (e.g., political objectives, security, etc.). There is much
more *unadvertised* abstract math research in the government sector that you might imagine. The only way to find out is to make applications that mention
the full range of your abilities and interests and see how agency recruiters
interpret your resume. For example, I can almost guarantee there is a lot of mathematics with security implications
for what you call 'theoretical computer science' that does not pop immediately to mind. But publishing results in journals will *probably not* be involved.

I think you need a fresh perspective and I can't recommend specifics that are
sure to be helpful. So generalities: Go to meetings, talk with recruiters, have lunch with
nonacademic colleagues about *their* interests, participate on this site with a 'name' and 'profile' that make you traceable to the persistent, put your (real) name on Linked In (if you can deal with
the email traffic *that* will generate), and so on. One decent 'thread' out of dozens may be all you need.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; it still is an issue. I have tried the government route, but it's been difficult to find something truly research-oriented. The projects I've worked on have been outside my control to decide on or steer (and security-type projects generally don't advertise their details beforehand); and, as you said, there are few opportunities for publication. There are certainly plenty of places that will hire people with backgrounds in math, but there are few that actually involve doing anything with that math.